# Cannot create schema in function/procedure in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Hello everybody I was developing management app for schools and I came across with this problem:

```
create or replace procedure create_school_schema(title text)
as
$BODY$
    create schema title;    
$BODY$
language sql
```

It does not hetting parameter value as schema name , instead taking 'title' as schema name?
With function it did nit work as well but  in return it is showing me my parameter value i am passing.

Comment: Why would you create a separate schema for each school instead of storing all the data in tables that span all the schools?  It looks like you have a more fundamental data modeling problem.

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for that

Comment: Lookslike this, I was creating management dashboard for schools, wanted to keep each school as schema with appropriate tables in it

Comment: So I should use ```EXECUTE``` command in my quieries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example function that uses `EXECUTE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.create_school_schema(title text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('CREATE SCHEMA %I', title);
    END;
$procedure$
;
```

To use `EXECUTE` you will need to use plpgsql language. Then use the [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function to add the `title` variable as an identifier to the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement. So:

```
\dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   
--------+----------
 public | postgres
 test   | postgres

call create_school_schema('school');
CALL

\dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   
--------+----------
 public | postgres
 school | postgres
 test   | postgres
```